# Angular2 - Lazy loading inside aux routers

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I'm back with another Angular2 question...

Currently I spend most of my time with R&D about a variety of client requests on the new Angular2 project we will be creating.
One of those requests was for the SPA to be able to handle a certain amount of tabs, so I am now researching on the use of aux router outlets that lazy load modules.

I have achieved to create a route mapping that works, but I would like to optimize it:

main router:

```
 export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'module1',
        outlet: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: 'wwwroot/build/modules/module1/module1.module#Module1Module'
    },
    {
        path: 'module2',
        outlet: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: 'wwwroot/build/modules/module2/module2.module#Module2Module'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent
    }
];
```

child router:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: 'Page1', outlet: 'tab1', component: Page1Component },
        { path: 'Page2', outlet: 'tab1', component: Page2Component },
        { path: 'Page1', outlet: 'tab2', component: Page1Component },
        { path: 'Page2', outlet: 'tab2', component: Page2Component },
    ])],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

working url:

> /(tab1:module1/(tab1:page1)//tab2:module2/(tab2:page2))

What I want to achieve on the url above is to omit the second reference for each outlet. My goal would be a url such as:

> /(tab1:module1/page1//tab2:module2/page2)

If I don't refer the outlet inside the lazy loaded module routing, then the page opens inside the main router-outlet instead of the aux.
Also, does anyone have some info on the following navigation options, in regard to the example above? I can't seem to find any detailed info on their arguments. I'm still stuck at `[path, {outlets: {outletName: outletPath}}`

- router.navigate()
- [routerLink] = ""

P.S. Please do not mind the different references on each tab. On the final product, all tabs will have access to the same modules/components.

Thank you all very much in advance!!
 Dimitris